# Using locate to only find directories containing the string "foo"

Tags: linux

Is is it possible to use the `locate` command to only find directories? To rephrase, I want to search for a directory, and exclude any result that is not a directory, such as files or symlinks to files.

While not necessary, I would like the solution to also return symlinks to other directories (but again, not files).

Lastly, I would like to exclude directories within foo, with one exception.  If a subdirectory of foo *also* contains a subdirectory with a name containing foo, I would prefer it be returned as well.

If the following files and directories exist...

```
/home/foo/
/home/foo/foo.txt
/home/foo/someotherdir/
/home/foo/someotherdir/food/
/food/
/var/www/foo -> /home/foo/
/var/www/food -> /home/food/index.html
```

Output would only contain...

```
/home/foo/
/home/foo/someotherdir/food/
/food/
/var/www/foo -> /home/foo/
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thank you for the responses. I am very deliberate in titling this for the `locate` command and not `find`.

Comment: Perhaps just use find? `find / -wholename '*foo*' -type d`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe a litte tricky but here it comes:

```
locate foo | xargs file -NF '|' |grep '| directory' | sed 's/| directory//g'
```

Comment: slightly ugly, but faster than `find` on the whole filesystem :-)  ***`IMPORTANT CAVEAT:`*** This will only find stuff in the locate command's database (some systems don't run `updatedb` as root, so there may be some missing items...)

Answer (score 3):

Locate only reads preprepared databases and not the filesystem.

Using find

directories containing foo

```
find /path -name '*foo*' -type d
```

links that contain foo, you need to read the link and test to see if the destination is a directory which requires a script

```
#!/bin/bash
f=$(readlink $1)
if [ -d "$f" ]
then
    echo $1
fi
```

use it like this

```
find /path -name '*foo*' -type l -exec script {} \;
```

Comment: I know locate only uses the prepared database from updatedb, and not the filesystem. I specifically was hoping to *not* use find, but rather locate because it runs faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
locate foo | sed 's%/[^/]*$%/%'
```

Edit: This just snaps all info out after the last slash.

Answer (score 0):

This one will do the job:

```
locate foo | grep "foo[^/]*/$"
```

It will be much quicker than the `find` options available but with the standard `locate` caveat that it could be up to 24 hours out of date.

Comment: Does your version of `locate` append `/` to directories? Mine doesn't seem to. (mlocate 0.24)